# Anaconda+Spyder+Windows Tensorflow installation

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

The topic describes the problem. I cannot install TF and use it in Anaconda withtin Spyder IDE on Windows. Installation of TF GPU v0.12.1 within this script successfully finishes:

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

However, I still get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a2e3a001c740>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/ERP/SRC/WorkloadPrediction/PythonScripts/test_pys/test_TF.py', wdir='D:/ERP/SRC/WorkloadPrediction/PythonScripts/test_pys')

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/ERP/SRC/WorkloadPrediction/PythonScripts/test_pys/test_TF.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

I ensured that Visual C++ x64 2015 Redist is installed. Also tried a lot of reinstallations, reboots, google solutions etc, but nothing helps.

Try to run this script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
a = tf.constant(10)
b = tf.constant(32)
print(sess.run(a + b))
```

Can you please advice something?

Thank you so much!
Artemiy

Comment: My recommendation for you is to wait until Tensorflow is available trough Anaconda and try again. Pip and conda packages (especially compiled ones like Tensorflow) are known to not interact that well.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you for your answer. That makes sense. However, the open question is what to use instead. Have you ever worked with https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/cognitive-toolkit/ ? Is it good?

Comment: I'm sure Tensorflow will be available in Anaconda soon (a month or so). I don't know about other toolkits, sorry.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba sounds good, thank you. But I will still wait for some other replies)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, you need to initialize TensorFlow outside its directory. If that is not your problem check if you have `MSVCP140.dll` installed in your system (see **NOTE** under [Pip Installation on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows)) considering your Cuda and cuDNN are properly installed and their directories set on your `%PATH%`.

Answer (score -1):

Update TensorFlow with

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```